# Angular auto resize text-area

Tags: angular, typescript, mat-form-field

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I wanted to set max height to text area so when user keeps adding text if it reaches max height it will add a scroll. But my current implementation is that it streches the modal , so If I add more text the modal becomes too long.

How do we make it that the modal will not be streched ? Thanks.

## html

```
 <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start start" class="full-width question-text" fxLayoutGap="12px">
          <mat-form-field style="height: auto; overflow: hidden;" class="pr-4" appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>Comments</mat-label>
            <div
            style="
              margin-right: 10px;
              overflow-y: auto;
              height: auto;
              max-height: 200px;
            "
          >
          <textarea cdkTextareaAutosize
          matTextareaAutosize
          matInput
          formControlName="comment"
          [required]="isCommentRequired()"
        ></textarea>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`overflow-y:scroll` put that in textarea css, it's not an angular issue but a CSS one, also remove the `overflow-y: auto` from parent div.

Comment: still the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried matAutosizeMinRows & matAutosizeMaxRows

```
<textarea matInput
              matTextareaAutosize
              [matAutosizeMinRows]="min"
              [matAutosizeMaxRows]="max"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://material.angular.io/cdk/text-field/overview#text-field-autosize-textarea) in the documentation of Angular Material (13.3.2)

In component:

```
import {CdkTextareaAutosize} from '@angular/cdk/text-field';
import {Component, NgZone, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {take} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'text-field-autosize-textarea-example',
  templateUrl: './text-field-autosize-textarea-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['./text-field-autosize-textarea-example.css'],
})
export class TextFieldAutosizeTextareaExample {
  constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone) {}

  @ViewChild('autosize') autosize: CdkTextareaAutosize;

  triggerResize() {
    // Wait for changes to be applied, then trigger textarea resize.
    this._ngZone.onStable.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(() => this.autosize.resizeToFitContent(true));
  }
}
```

In template:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Autosize textarea</mat-label>
  <textarea matInput
            cdkTextareaAutosize
            #autosize="cdkTextareaAutosize"
            cdkAutosizeMinRows="1"
            cdkAutosizeMaxRows="5"></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a text event listener, for the example below `onTextChanged`, to change the rows attribute value,

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>{{label}}</mat-label>
    <textarea matInput type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ text }}" (input)="onTextChanged($event)" rows="{{numberOfRows}}"></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

Then in the event listener function initialize the numberOfRows with the number of new lines the user has added.

```
function onTextChanged(event: Event) {
    numberOfRows = event.target.value.split('\n').length;
}
```

then set the max-height using css:

```
textarea {
    max-height: 300px;
}
```